# Where might I observe refugees escaping across the North Korea-China or North Korea Russia border illegally?

Tags: china, borders, russia, north-korea

I will try to visit northern China and/or eastern Russia on this trip.

I've visited South Korea many times and I'm really interested in the plight of North Koreans trying to flee from the repressive regime in the their country.

Which spots on the border are known for escapes? I know I've seen documentaries and news stories on it but don't know if they said where.

Actually even if I don't see anybody going for it it would still feel amazing to be at a place where I know people do often attempt this amazing personal challenge to find their freedom.

Is there somewhere near Weihai perhaps?

Comment: Presumably if it was well known, the border guards would watch those places..

Comment: Presumably there is a long border and few border guards..

Comment: In any case well known answers don't need Stack Exchange questions.

Comment: @MarkMayo The DDR wasn't keen on having its citizens head west, and tried really hard to stop them, but even they didn't always manage! General areas could be well known, even if specifics changed

Comment: The [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_Korean_defectors) on Wikipedia is astonishly detailed about the routes the refugees choose and which problems they had. I do not think there is much too add, so I used a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: No offense meant, but is the question triggered by [this](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45511/where-might-i-observe-people-sneaking-across-the-vietnam-cambodian-border-illega?rq=1) ? I must say that the longer I think about this, I feel more and more irritated by your request because you are not asking for a memorial, you want to see an escape attempt personally...what would you feel if you in fact see someone trying to cross the border who is caught and screaming helplessly while brought back to await a terrible fate ? Do you find that exciting ?!

Comment: I'm assuming there are no memorials in China. Probably not in Russia either. Possibly in South Korea, but nobody is making across that border as far as I know. My question was triggered by that question. I may not see people escaping but it would feel great to stand in the spot where many people fled despotism. I would feel terrible and helpless and want even more to find a way to bring and end to such evil.

Comment: The area near Dandong might prove fruitful. You might have to go some distance from the main bridge spans over the Yalu and hang around some sketchy industrial areas at night, but it seems crossing the Tumen river is more popular. The people doing the human trafficking are criminals- this seems like a very dangerous thing to attempt.

Comment: The refugees has been caught already before you know the route

Comment: I'm right now in former East Germany. I think of the million or so people physically closest to me, 99.99% will find your question disgusting.

Comment: @hippietrail, an interesting white paper published by the European Alliance for Human Rights in North Korea was circulated today which contains a chapter called "Escape from North Korea". I don't know if this question is still current or active, but you might find the report useful as a reference.

Answer (score 7):

I am sure such question can not be answered with any reasonable detailed place.

- first of all if such place would be known to a broad audience, most probably it would be known to law enforcement and would be closed (like asking on the forum for a suggestion where to find gold in Alaska. It is useless because if people knew where to find it, all of it would be found and you end up with no gold)
- finding places to escape and closing these places is everlasting battle, and the situation changes pretty frequently. So if there was a place which people were used a month ago, there is a big chance that it is already closed and monitored

In addition, this is not some tourist destination and remote forgotten places can be dangerous. Not all people who are trying to run are kind, intelligent people who are "oppressed by despotism". You can encounter a contrabandist or a gun seller who try to kidnap you or shoot without warning. If you think that criminals is your only problem, then what do you expect a border patrol would do to you if they will notice a random guy walking around close to a place known to be relevant for a refugee escaping. Most probably they would not satisfied that you were curious and think that you are either trying to cross the border or an accomplice which helps someone else to cross the border (try to hang out in a drug/prostitution related region in your favorite country to have a slight experience of what can happen). And at least in Russia the conversation between a potential suspect and law enforcement is not friendly at all.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you got through (amur river), Which also touch the boarder of north Russia and there are also travelling agent at the side of that river, Who want small commition to cross the boarder but, There is a lot of danger there.....

Comment: Do you know this from personal experience?

Comment: No, But i know the man, Who do that in his life