# I am interested in visiting a refugee camp. What would be a good place to do so in Europe?

Tags: europe, destinations

My [previous question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/49891/is-it-legal-safe-to-visit-the-calais-border-crossing) concerning the Calais border crossing received answers indicating it's probably not a good place to visit. However I am still very much interested in exploring the current refugee crisis in person.

What would be a good location to visit a refugee camp, particularly the ones receiving people who come to the EU by boat? My reasoning is that I would like to get a good understanding of this highly controversial issue and there's no better way than personal contact.

Some ideas include:

- [Malta](http://www.unhcr.org.mt/)
- [Lampedusa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lampedusa_immigrant_reception_center)
- [Ceuta and Melilla](http://www.unhcr.org/4416889b0.html)

Comment: All you need to do is go to Lampedusa and wait on the docks. However I wouldn't do this for the sake of exploring the refugee crisis. Rather I'd go there to help or not go at all. I've been there. I've seen the suffering. It's not for the faint hearted.

Comment: @JoErNanO if there are short-term volunteering opportunities, I'd be highly interested as well.

Comment: It's best to get some wearable credentials from a charity (JCWI or ILPA) or the media or even the UN.  Otherwise expect to be detained as a suspected trafficker and issued a prohibitive steps order.

Comment: @GayotFow I've emailed a few charity organizations working with migration camps, hopefully they'll reply. The only thing I hear from journalists in my country is how the migrants are lazy and are about to bring down the EU.

Comment: @JonathanReez, I have a friend who does it.  She's very defensive about people's assumptions where migrants are concerned, I suggest not bringing laziness or etc up with those types of people.

Comment: @JoErNanO I'm not writing down *any* assumptions about the immigrants, I would like to meet them and get all of the information from scratch :)

Comment: How about asking [the Italian Red Cross section in Lampedusa](https://www.facebook.com/crocerossaitalianadilampedusa)? Note that any volunteering organisation will require you to train before sending you on the field. Indeed it's often harmful to send untrained help during crisis situations. Most self-improvised volunteers often end up doing more harm than good in situations requiring specific skills and training. I'm a divemaster but I'd never improvise my own amateur sea rescue team. This is not to discourage you but rather to allow you to see the full picture: helping requires commitment.

Comment: non-EEA will need a work permit, not applicable to you, but to others reading the question.  Suggest you mention that you are EEA.

Comment: I sent her a DM on Twitter.  She will think it's slightly pervy, but may have a better idea.

Comment: @GayotFow I'm actually surprised charity organizations aren't pushing for more people to meet the immigrants, it seems like an excellent opportunity to both raise money and increase awareness. And Thanks!

Comment: @JonathanReez There is substantially more to getting someone into a refugee camp than just opening the door and saying "go talk to people". For starters they have to make sure you aren't a drug seller, human trafficer etc. Every time someone does this a refugee worker has to take time off helping the refugees to deal with the 'tourist'. I absolutely back up what the others have said - if you are really interested in learning more about this situation, talk first to the organizations on the ground.

Comment: You will not get a "good understanding" of the issues just by dropping in for a few days and having a cuppa with desperate people— who by the way, are not interchangeable with one another. Rethink this entire adventure, starting with your assumptions that your personal contact will prove enlightening about a variegated international phenomenon of which countless stories have already been written in the international press.

Comment: @JonathanReez, do you want to get *inside* the centre? Or just hang around outside the fence?

Comment: It boggles my mind that with all of the advice and recommendations to NOT do this, you have posted a bounty for the opposite.

Comment: @CGCampbell I think it's an interesting question.

Comment: It's unfortunate that this has a bounty on it, because at its heart, it's a list question, and therefor off topic to Stack Exchange.

Comment: @CGCampbell we have lots of similar questions, such as the one about Thailand alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you understand that you're coming from a place of prividlege to be able to choose to be there, and know how to stay out of the way or provide help as asked, there are absolutely places where you would be able to experience a taste of what's going on with putting yourself or others in danger.

[Noboarder](http://www.noborder.org/) network has information about the situation and organizes volunteer events and camps for awareness. I would suggest trying to find such an event or getting in contact with some of the network members.

Traskirchen is home to an immigration detention facility, a bit outside of Vienna in Lower Austria. It has a strong local volunteer community providing grass roots help and political assistance to asylum seekers and refugees. While it's day release detention facility and not a camp, there have been refugees who refused to continue spending the night in the extremely overcrowded facility and have left to protest policies that push them, despite documented human rights violations, back to places like Hungary where they first entered the Schengen Zone. These people have been staying in camps of outside a Viennese church sympathetic to the cause. (Austrian Public Broadcasting's [FM4 occasionally reports on the situation](http://fm4.orf.at/search?q=traiskirchen&sort=date_desc), sometimes in English.)